# How to Hide Duplicates in a Query for Just One Field in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm pritty new in this topic and need help...
How to Hide Duplicates in a Query for Just One Field in SQL? For example, I have a table

- 1, 122, 123, 6
- 2, 122, 156, 7
- 3, 122, 188, 6
- 4, 101, 186, 8

and I want to get table

- 122, 123, 6
- empty,156, 7
- empty,188, 6
- 101, 186, 8

"Emty" means that this cell should be emty. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can i use stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT, col4 INT)
INSERT @t VALUES 
(1, 122, 123, 69),
(2, 122, 156, 7),
(3, 122, 188, 6),
(4, 101, 186, 8)

SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col1) = 1 THEN col2 END col2_New
        , col3
        , col4
FROM    @t
ORDER BY
        col1
```

Only the first occurrence of a `col2` gets it's value written in the result set (values are ordered by `col1` ascending), otherwise the value is NULL (which in database terms means no value defined). It uses TSQL `ROW_NUMBER` function, you can read about it **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**. Call to `ROW_NUMBER` function is enclosed in a `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... END` conditional expression that makes it possible to only write out value of `col2` if it is the first occurrence of a certain value.

Comment: Great! You're welcome, if you find this answer helpful you can mark it as correct. You can accept an answer like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)